# Customizing the JSON received from Twitter API

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I have a web service that return JSON of a number of tweets from a twitter profile. However I want to customize how the tweets look on my page but I have no idea on how to access each separate part of the JSON. For example I just want the the image and the actual tweet (retweets included) to show on my page. How can this be done?

I found a tutorial on this but it doesn't help much as it never describe how to access each section of a tweet.

[Example of Customizing Tweets](http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/custom-twitter-feed-integration-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all parse JSON to JS object

Modern browsers support JSON.parse().

```
var arr_from_json = JSON.parse( json_string );
```

In browsers that don't, you can include the [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library.

Then you just need to access and modify the object's properties.

Comment: the properties that is what I am trying to find. What are they so I can place the objects in the right place

Comment: I don't know exactly what are they. But you can do `console.log(arr_from_json) and see it yourself.

Comment: Isn't it $.parseJSON()?